# How to make a Collection<String> object from comma separated values

Tags: java

I have a `String` object like

```
final String demoString = "1,2,19,12";
```

Now I want to create a `Collection<String>` from it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Guava:

```
List<String> it = Splitter.on(',').splitToList(demoString);
```

Standard JDK:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(demoString.split(","))
```

Commons / Lang:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(demoString, ","));
```

Note that you can't add or remove Elements from a List created by Arrays.asList, since the List is backed by the supplied array and arrays can't be resized. If you need to add or remove elements, you need to do this:

```
// This applies to all examples above
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( /*etc */ ))
```

Comment: No no i want in Collection<String> and not as List<String>

Comment: A List<String> is a Collection<String>. You can change all of the above variable types to Collection<string>

Comment: On guava also: `Splitter.on(',').splitToList(demoString)`

Comment: @ToKra that method didn't exist when this answer was written

Answer (score 1):

Simple and good,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(string.split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `List<String>` and assign it to `Collection<String>` as List extends Collection.

```
final String demoString = "1,2,19,12";

Collection<String> collection = List.of(demoString.split(","));
```